# Highcharts setExtremes() does not display the correct interval for one day

Tags: jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a chart that by default displays yearly data. 
I also have 3 buttons that allows me to zoomIn/Out on specific intervals (yearly/weekly/daily). I do this by setting a specific interval on **setExtremes()** function.
E.g: weekly:

```
$('#weeklyView').click(function () {
   var chart = $('.chart-stor').highcharts();
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            Date.UTC(2015, 0, 5),
            Date.UTC(2015, 0, 12)
        );
    });
```

Weekly interval selection works perfectly. However when I do the same for daily view it displays data for about 5 days and not only for the day selected:

```
$('#dailyView').click(function () {
        var chart = $('.chart-stor').highcharts();
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
            Date.UTC(2015, 6, 1),
            Date.UTC(2015, 6, 1)
        );
   });
```

How exactly should I proceed to make sure that the chart displays the exact range I set using setExtremes() function, on daily view?

Comment: Set directly `minRange`. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange).

Comment: @PawełFus: Thanks! it worked with minRange set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RANGESELECTOR option in HighCharts

```
rangeSelector: {
                        buttons: [{
                            type: '',
                            count: 2,
                            text: 'My dates'
                        },{
                            type: 'hour',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1h'
                        }, {
                            type: 'day',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1d'
                        }, {
                            type: 'month',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1m'
                        }, {
                            type: 'year',
                            count: 1,
                            text: '1y'
                        }, {
                            type: 'all',
                            text: 'All'
                        }],
            },
```

And then use `afterSetextremes` options

```
    afterSetExtremes: function(e) {
                            if (e.trigger == "rangeSelectorButton" && 
                                e.rangeSelectorButton.text == "My dates"){
                                // it is your button that caused this,
                                // so setExtrememes to your custom
                                // have to do in timeout to let
                                // highcharts finish processing events...
                                setTimeout(function()

{Highcharts.charts[0].xAxis[0].setExtremes
    (custom dates from,custom date to)  }, 1);
             }
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/Aeaz3/23/)**

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use a more specific date constructor.

2) And You have to add timezone offset to make the range present correctly.

```
$('#dailyView').click(function () {
    var chart = $('.chart-stor').highcharts();
    var timezoneOffset = Highcharts.getOptions().global.timezoneOffset * 60 * 1000;

    chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(
        Date.UTC(2015, 6, 1, 0, 0, 0) + timezoneOffset,
        Date.UTC(2015, 6, 1, 23, 59, 59) + timezoneOffset
    );
});
```